# How to see the image using PackIconMaterial before running?

Tags: c#

I have used MahApps.Metro.IconPacks 2.3.0 dll for adding icon  in UI.

It only appear while operating.

likewise, I want to see the icon before operating  through UI

Thank you in advance

```
<Button x:Name="btnExit" Style="{DynamicResource Button}" Margin="10,110,10,0" Background="White">
                    <StackPanel Style="{DynamicResource ButtonPanel}">
                        <iconPacks:PackIconMaterial Foreground="#FFEDC87E" Kind="Folder" Width="20"    Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        <TextBlock Style="{DynamicResource ButtonText}" Text="Folder"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button>
```